# How to store zero as array data in C

Tags: c++

I have array in which i want to store values like this 1203

```
   char* arr= new char[10];
    arr[0] = 1;
    arr[1] = 2;
    arr[2] = 0;
    arr[3] = 3;
```

but after storing 0 i am not able to see any further data bcs it'll consider that as end of the data. is there any way to manage this??

Comment: Why using char to store integers?

Comment: Please post the code you uses to read/process the data. Sounds like you're using string functions.

Comment: If your data are always integers, then use an integer array. By using a character array, the "0" is the null terminator.

Comment: " i am not able to see any further data " See where? In the debugger? This is nothing to worry about, the debugger thinks you are processing a zero terminated string.

Comment: @suma: yes in debugger i am not able to see further data

Comment: This is not C you are posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0` means end of string in the `char*`.

Because `char*` is a string in C and it exists to be used as char array not as `integer` array. All function related on string are intended to be used with a string.

You can use `int*` to store `integer`s.

You can do the binary operations manually like this :

```
int value = 1245; 

char* temp = new char[4]; 

temp[0] = (char)(value >> 24);
temp[1] = (char)(value >> 16);
temp[2] = (char)(value >> 8); 
temp[3] = (char)value;

return temp;
```

you can use `uint8_t` or `int` instead of `char`.

the `(char*)((int)value)` is not good because you cast the `int` to `char*`, but the `char*` is the variable `temp` not the number to be stored in `temp`.

If pointers is a new thing for you, it will be helpful to do some exercises in pointers : manipulate arrays, lists,...

Comment: from CppDepend:sorry it's returning only 00 i.e i think only 1 byte

Comment: @poppy : you want only 1 byte ? I corrected my answer. You want a byte from 0 to 255 or a byte from -127 to 128 ?

Comment: no i dont want only one byte for value 1245 the expected value is [0, 0, 4, -35] i.e 000004dd but i think i am getting only first value

Comment: @poppy: using the code in my answer gives the result you want: "0,0,4,dd" in temp...

Comment: thank you for your suggetions.The methods which you are changing all are working but the main problem is I am compiling this code in carbide c/c++ IDE(synmbian app) so here if i see value of temp in debug mode i am not seeing any value and even length's also 0 but when i assign values to another variable in reverse order like this char* where = new char[10];  where[0] = temp[3];
       where[1] = temp[2];
       where[2] = temp[1];
       where[3] = temp[0]; able to see only two values i.e -41, 4

Comment: @poppy: you see this because you are using the wron gcontainer : `char*`. try using `unit8_t` instead. char* is only aimed to be uised as a string. so the 0 is interpreted as end of string sor the debugger stops reading the array... that's why you see only -35 and 4 in reverse array. using uint8_t* or maybe int* should resolving the problem. the debugger will not continue reading the array till its end not till the first number 0 its find.

Answer (score 2):

You are storing integers in a character array. Try something like this:

```
char* arr= new char[10];
arr[0] = '1';
arr[1] = '2';
arr[2] = '0';
arr[3] = '3';
```

Comment: And please do not forget the terminator, else you see a lot more.

Comment: sorry the actual code which i am trying to convert is something like this in java  : ` return new byte[] {
       (byte)(value >>> 24),
       (byte)(value >>> 16),
       (byte)(value >>> 8),
       (byte)value};` where value is int.

Comment: @Aamir,@Eric Postpischil,@Gamecat :I have written like this value 1245; char* temp = new char[4];
   temp =((char*)((int)value >> 24),
    (char*)((int)value >> 16),
    (char*)((int)value >> 8),
    (char*)((int)value)); return temp; in java it'll return 0,0,4,-45 but i am not getting any value.

Comment: @Aamir: I have written like this value 1245; char* temp = new char[4]; temp =((char*)((int)value >> 24), (char*)((int)value >> 16), (char*)((int)value >> 8), (char*)((int)value)); return temp; in java it'll return 0,0,4,-45 but i am not getting any value.

Comment: @Hicham from CppDepend Team: i am using char* as alternative for byte so i have to use char* only.

Comment: @poppy : ok. the problem is here : `(char*)((int)value));`. you have to remove the caxt to `char*` and put a cast to `char` then`. you can also `uint8_t` insteed of `char`.

Answer (score 2):

You're syntax was in C++. But, disregarding that, you could use `snprintf` to store your data:

```
snprintf(arr, 10, "%d", 1203);
```

Answer (score 1):

You say you are “not able to see any further data”, but you did not describe what you are doing to see the data. Are you printing it with printf and a %s format? Are you displaying it in a debugger?

When you use string operations on char data, a zero commonly indicates the end of the string. This is true when using %s with printf or when using strcpy or strlen. However, an array of char may be treated numerically. After `arr[3] = 3;`, 3 is stored in arr[3], and it is just a matter of seeing it.

You can print char data as decimal numerals by using the %d format with printf. %d prints one number, so you need to pass it one number to print, such as arr[0], arr[3], or, in a loop, arr[i]. This is different from %s, where you pass a pointer (such as the array, which becomes a pointer to the first element) to printf, and it prints multiple characters.

If you are looking at the char array with a debugger, you can likely look at arr[3] individually to see that it contains 3. Your debugger may have a way to display an array of char as a sequence of decimal numerals instead of as a string.

Comment: :I have written like this value 1245; char* temp = new char[4]; temp =((char*)((int)value >> 24), (char*)((int)value >> 16), (char*)((int)value >> 8), (char*)((int)value)); return temp; in java it'll return 0,0,4,-45 but i am not getting any value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write it as:

```
char* arr= new char[10];
arr[0] = '1';
arr[1] = '2';
arr[2] = '0';
arr[3] = '3';
```

Such that you do not need to use zero-value which indicates the termination as said by Aamir

Answer (score 0):

Your debugger tool, as most, will take notice that it is displaying a char array. That from of data is commonly used in C as storage for null-terminated strings.

A null-terminated string, if the named wasn't revealing enough, is a bunch of characters (printable or not), finished by a zero. That mark tells printf and alike when to stop printing.

It also told the function used by the debugger to stop printing. To avoid this you should either tell your debugger "this ain't no string, fool!" or simply redeclare as short.

You seam to be a starter so take this advice: forget about ints, use short or longs. The int size is machine dependent, and it will get you into "I assummed it was Xbits" trouble later on.

Comment: I would upvote, but I will not because of "use short or longs." Shorts and longs are machine dependent as well. int is a good default type to use.

Comment: @Suma, perhaps you're thinking about a Word. A short is always 16bit, Long is always 32bit, and Long long is always 64bit.

Comment: Let's make it more interesting: give us an example of a compiler not implementing the sizes as short in 2B, long in 4B, long long in 8B. I'll eat my hat.

Comment: 16b or 8b CPUs still exist as embedded, and they frequently implement int as 2B. Look for PIC or Atmel-AVR. You probably implicitly assume PC.

Comment: Indeed, most likely an int is 2B, but not always: I had int=1B or 2B (option) for <7.XX versions of the Mplab (haven't checked since), compiling for 16F688. Shorts were fixed 2B, though. Hence my advice.

Answer (score 0):

you can use write on Unix platforms:

```
man 2 write;
```

this function allow you to specify the length of element to print.

but for sure, `snprintf` is a portable solution (as `size_t` size allow you to do it so).

doing that be careful in order not to segfault.

nb:
you can set char with value like `0` or `255`, or with negative value if it's a `signed char`...
you can set it with `0`, or with `48`, there are no differences.

Answer (score 0):

**char* arr= new char[10];**

as you have defined array of characters, when you assign 0 to any array member and pass whole array or print the array, the reason it takes it as data end because 0 is actually NULL and every character string is terminated by NULL. So if you really want to assign value of character 0 then you can assign ascii value of 0 or '0'.

hope it helps

Comment: :thank you but as you suggested if i store like this '0' then it's storing it as "\x30" entire value Ó\x04\x30\x30.